# How to force Civ 5 resolution on Linux?

Tags: civilization-5, linux

Civilization 5 insists that I can only set portrait-style resolutions (such as 1200x1920), presumably since [one of my screens is in that mode](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.screenlayout/right-tack.sh). I would like to be able to play in landscape mode, as originally intended. I tried setting the game to **windowed mode** and and setting the resolution in `~/.local/share/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini`:

```
WindowResX = 1920
WindowResY = 1280
FullScreen = 0
```

However, when I start the game it resets to 1024x1280, and overwrites my settings. I assume since [complex multi-monitor setups](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=511370) are possible, this should be no problem at all.